# Basic regex capture

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to capture a string between 2 strings.I'm not experienced with regex. I want to capture the town name in the following string:

```
On  April  6,  2016,  the  Town  of  Woodstock  auctioned 
±
14.00
```

I've tried the most basic capture attempt:

```
town of (.*) auctioned
```

that I can think of , but I'm not getting any match at all. A link is below. what am I doing wrong?

[see here](http://pythex.org/?regex=town%20of%20(.*%3F)%20auctioned&test_string=%0AOn%20%20April%20%206%2C%20%202016%2C%20%20the%20%20Town%20%20of%20%20Woodstock%20%20auctioned%20%0A%C2%B1%0A14.00%0A&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=1&verbose=0)

Comment: Nearly 5k rep and you can't give a [mcve]? Come on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, regexes are case-sensitive by default. Use the `(?i)` inline modifier to change that (assuming a regex engine that doesn't expect its modifiers after the regex).

Second, whitespace is treated like any other character. If the text contains two spaces between words, then your regex won't match if it uses only one space.

Lastly, you probably should use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
(?i)town\s+of\s+(.*?)\s+auctioned
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, including for the explanation. I didn't think about the whitespace obviously

Answer (score 1):

If you say that the regex would start with town of and end with auctioned

then:

```
/town\s+of\s+(.*?)\s+auctioned/ig
```

here /i makes it case insensitive in javascript.
here capture group 1 contains your town name

Comment: `\s` is already a character class, you don't need the square brackets around it.